# Application level access management for models accessed through the forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have added the forge viewer to a web application in which different users may have access to different drawings/models.

Our current implementation of this functionality makes our own backend function as a proxy between our frontend and the Autodesk Forge API. Here, the backend adds the Authorization header after authenticating to the Autodesk API.

While this is fine for uploading and translating models to an Autodesk bucket, retrievel of these translated models by the Viewer through our own backend as a proxy seems unnecessary. For example, Azure or AWS object storage allows for creating private buckets that can be accessed directly through a "signed" URL. This way the frontend client only has to obtain such a signed URL from the backend and can then retrieve the file from the Azure/AWS bucket directly.

**Is it possible to do something similar (creating a private bucket that can be accessed directly from the client) with the Autodesk Forge API?**

If not, would it possible to store the translated model SVF file in our own Azure/AWS bucket and point the viewer to that location instead? This way we use Autodesk Forge for translation of the model and we can control access through private buckets in Azure/AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question (creating a bucket that could be accessed directly by a client), unfortunately that is not something we support.

Regarding the possibility to serve SVF files yourself, and point Forge Viewer to their custom locations, that *is* possible but not recommended. The only requirement of the Terms of Use is that the Forge Viewer assets (JavaScript, CSS, images, etc.) must be served from the Autodesk domain.